# open office api text size

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, uno

I am using `open office API` with `Java UNO`. I need to get *size* of *selected text* in the document content (for example embedded pictures have own size in `mm` but text inserted via `XText.insertString(...)` method doesn't have any **size**). 
In other words: I want to get size (preferably in `mm`) of the box which surrounds *part* of *text* (it can be *whole paragraph* or *selected text* via some type of *cursor*). 
Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I think there is no option to achieve this at the moment. For my purposes I write small method for getting height of the paragraph in 1/100 mm.

Here is how this method works:

1. Get `XTextViewCursor` of the `XTextDocumment` controller for going left/right.
2. Go to paragraph to measure.
3. Loop through paragraph getting each char. For each char do: check its height (`CharHeight` property of the paragraph); get `XLineCursor` from `XTextViewCursor` and check if there is end of the line - if is then add (to the result) biggest height of the character in line.

This is temporary solution (still wait for something better) and has number of bugs (example line-spacing different than single; paragraph should only contain text) but maybe it will be helpful for someone.